# jquery - if/else-statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, transition

So, I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var case_menu = 0;
    var case_heading = 0;
    var case_headerbar = 0;

    $(".spinner-spin2").click(function(){
        if (case_menu == 0){ // initial status
            $(".menu").addClass("showmenu");
            $(".headingwrapper").addClass("extraspace");
            $(".logo").removeClass("logo_animation_long");
            $(".logo").addClass("logo_animation_short");
            $(".logo").addClass("logovisibility");
            $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogo_animation_short");
            $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogo_animation_long");
            $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogovisibility");
            $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_animation_short");
            $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_animation_long");
            $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_visibility");
            $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottom_animation_short");
            $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottom_animation_long");
            $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottomvisibility");
            $(".headerbar").addClass("extraspace2");
            $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_comein");
            $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_goout");
            $(".headerbar").addClass("header_animation_spacer");
        } else (case_menu == 1){ // status: menu out
            $(".menu").removeClass("showmenu");
            $(".headingwrapper").removeClass("extraspace");
            $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogo_animation_long");
            $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogo_animation_short");
            $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogovisibility");
            $(".logo").removeClass("logo_animation_short");
            $(".logo").addClass("logo_animation_long");
            $(".logo").removeClass("logovisibility");
            $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_animation_long");
            $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_animation_short");
            $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_visibility");
            $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottom_animation_long");
            $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottom_animation_short");
            $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottomvisibility");
            $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_comein");
            $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_goout");
            $(".headerbar").addClass("header_animation_spacer");
            $(".headerbar").removeClass("extraspace2");
        } else if{

        }
    });
});
```

It's included in my index.php and should just apply some css-transitions concerning the sidemenu when the menu-button is clicked. All it does is nothing, so that's why I'm here.

Previously, I had this code, which worked fine:

```
    function logo_handler1() {
          $(".menu").addClass("showmenu");
          $(".headingwrapper").addClass("extraspace");
          $(".logo").removeClass("logo_animation_long");
          $(".logo").addClass("logo_animation_short");
          $(".logo").addClass("logovisibility");
          $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogo_animation_short");
          $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogo_animation_long");
          $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogovisibility");
          $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_animation_short");
          $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_animation_long");
          $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_visibility");
          $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottom_animation_short");
          $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottom_animation_long");
          $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottomvisibility");
          $(".headerbar").addClass("extraspace2");
          $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_comein");
          $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_goout");
          $(".headerbar").addClass("header_animation_spacer");
          $(".spinner-spin2").one("click", logo_handler2);
      }
      function logo_handler2() {
          $(".menu").removeClass("showmenu");
          $(".headingwrapper").removeClass("extraspace");
          $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogo_animation_long");
          $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogo_animation_short");
          $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogovisibility");
          $(".logo").removeClass("logo_animation_short");
          $(".logo").addClass("logo_animation_long");
          $(".logo").removeClass("logovisibility");
          $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_animation_long");
          $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_animation_short");
          $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_visibility");
          $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottom_animation_long");
          $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottom_animation_short");
          $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottomvisibility");
          $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_comein");
          $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_goout");
          $(".headerbar").addClass("header_animation_spacer");
          $(".headerbar").removeClass("extraspace2");
          $(".spinner-spin2").one("click", logo_handler1);
      }
      $(".spinner-spin2").one("click", logo_handler1);
```

It does just the same as the new code did, but since I have to handle more cases of transitions now, I wanted to transform this into if-statements which should apply the correct transition-code and transitions based on what situation is present.

I can't see anything wrong with the new code or I just overlooked something... Can you help?

Comment: `else (case_menu == 1)` isn't valid. You might want `else if (case_menu == 1)`

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: changed this, still not working :/ @j08691

Comment: If statements are a fairly rudimentary aspect of programming. Look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: no errors in the console, sadly @Pointy

Comment: have you added some logs and seen if your code is going to the right places?

Answer (score 3):

change

```
} else (case_menu == 1){
```

to

```
} else if(case_menu == 1){
```

then change

```
} else if{
```

to

```
} else {
```

Comment: @LarsE. did you make sure you have all matching braces?

Comment: @LarsE. you need to post the code thats actually changing the case_menu and other vars. maybe the error is there, because maybe } else if(case_menu == 1){ should really be } else if(case_menuheader == 1){  or something like that

Answer (score 1):

If statements (and html/javascript in general) execute in a linear fashion. The problem with your code is it is checking the first block, finding it false, and then not recognizing the second block as valid code. If statements must always be in this format:

```
if (condition) {
    //initial check
} else if (condition) {
    //second check for other condition
} else if (condition) {
    //third check, as many of these checks may be added
} else {
    //if nothing else, this is what should be done. Think of this as 
    //"default" in a case statement
}
```

`else` statements cannot have arguments, or come before `else if` statements. They must be last.
Here is your modified code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var case_menu = 0;
var case_heading = 0;
var case_headerbar = 0;

$(".spinner-spin2").click(function(){
    if (case_menu == 0){ // initial status
        $(".menu").addClass("showmenu");
        $(".headingwrapper").addClass("extraspace");
        $(".logo").removeClass("logo_animation_long");
        $(".logo").addClass("logo_animation_short");
        $(".logo").addClass("logovisibility");
        $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogo_animation_short");
        $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogo_animation_long");
        $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogovisibility");
        $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_animation_short");
        $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_animation_long");
        $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_visibility");
        $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottom_animation_short");
        $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottom_animation_long");
        $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottomvisibility");
        $(".headerbar").addClass("extraspace2");
        $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_comein");
        $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_goout");
        $(".headerbar").addClass("header_animation_spacer");
    } else if (case_menu == 1){ // status: menu out
        $(".menu").removeClass("showmenu");
        $(".headingwrapper").removeClass("extraspace");
        $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogo_animation_long");
        $(".logo_blackedout").addClass("blacklogo_animation_short");
        $(".logo_blackedout").removeClass("blacklogovisibility");
        $(".logo").removeClass("logo_animation_short");
        $(".logo").addClass("logo_animation_long");
        $(".logo").removeClass("logovisibility");
        $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_animation_long");
        $(".navfooter").addClass("navfooter_animation_short");
        $(".navfooter").removeClass("navfooter_visibility");
        $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottom_animation_long");
        $(".menu .bottom").addClass("bottom_animation_short");
        $(".menu .bottom").removeClass("bottomvisibility");
        $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_comein");
        $(".headerbar").removeClass("header_animation_goout");
        $(".headerbar").addClass("header_animation_spacer");
        $(".headerbar").removeClass("extraspace2");
    } else {

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Alright, after I've already looked through my index a few times I looked again and found one space too much in the linking to the js. The js actually was fine all the time, I'm sorry for bugging you with this crap. Shame on me. I had the format right but changed it out of "desperation" to see if anything else works. Thanks anyone, nevertheless! :)